# Running flutter pub get i get an error, Cannot Find executable for pub.bat

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I' have recently upgraded flutter to its latest version, and after that i could not add any more packages to my pubspec.yaml file. Could anyone please help me with this issue?

After running flutter pub get command i get this output:

```
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for
C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat.".

A crash report has been written to C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Projects\newapp\flutter_06.log.
```

The file 'C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat.' doesn't exists in my pc.

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.50.1)    
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Does this file exist on your device : C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat

Comment: No, it doesnt exist in my device.

Comment: Where is your dart-sdk folder, the folder in which you installed dart? It's important to ensure that the dart SDK is in the ENVIRONMENT PATH.

Comment: C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\

This is the dart-sdk location

Comment: Try running this command : pub cache repair

Comment: I've tried it, but i get the same output as when running pub get

Comment: Last thing to try is rename the cache folder C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache to something random C:\Users\manup\Desktop\Flutter\flutter\bin\sumrandom and run flutter upgrade . Hopefully the directory structure will be rebuilt.

Comment: tried it but it didnt work, thank you anyways